# I have to parse the contents of webpage and show all headings as categories in dropdown menu & all sentences inside that heading mapped to category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have to parse the contents of a webpage and show all the headings as categories in dropdown menu and all the sentences inside that heading mapped to the category. For example: I have a webpage which is something like this:

Fruits:
Apple is a fruit
Mango is a fruit
Watermelon is a fruit

Animal:
Human is an animal
Cat is an animal
Dog is an animal

Car:
Ford is a car
Hyundai is a car
Audi is a car

Now my objective is to parse this webpage and show a drop-down menu of 'Fruit' 'animal' and 'car'. and upon selection of category, all the sentences pertaining to that category should be displayed.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Start with showing what code you have so far, that's relative to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the web page text into a JSON object.

Then iterate the JSON Object to create a select item

HTML Code:

```
<div id="target">
Fruits:
Apple is a fruit
Mango is a fruit
Watermelon is a fruit

Animal:
Human is an animal
Cat is an animal
Dog is an animal

Car:
Ford is a car
Hyundai is a car
Audi is a car
</div>
<select name="category" id="category"></select>
<div id="output">Please select a cateogry<div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
target=document.getElementById("target").innerHTML;

lines=target.split("\n");

json_array=[];
var obj={};
obj.name="";
obj.array=[];
for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
lines[i]=lines[i].replace(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g,'');

if(lines[i].indexOf(":")!=-1){
  if(obj.name!=""){
    json_array.push(obj);
    obj=new Object();
    obj.name=lines[i].replace(":","");
    obj.array=[];
  }
  else
  obj.name=lines[i].replace(":","");
}
else{
    if(lines[i].length>0){
            obj.array.push(lines[i]);
    }
   }
}
 json_array.push(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json_array));
menu=document.getElementById("category");
for(i=0;i<json_array.length;i++){
 var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = json_array[i].name;
    opt.innerHTML = json_array[i].name;
menu.appendChild(opt);

}
menu.addEventListener("change", function() {
   for(i=0;i<json_array.length;i++){
            if(menu.value == json_array[i].name){
        output.innerHTML="";

        for(j=0;j<json_array[i].array.length;j++){
            output.innerHTML+=json_array[i].array[j]+"<br>";
        }
        }

   }


});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1j586zky/2/)

Comment: @Learner I did this effort seeing its your first day on SO! Please accept my answer and make it worth my time! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @joey. I will try and share the result.

Comment: Welcome @Learner, However I will suggest you the next time you have a question try googling the query, you'll probably find links to previous stack overflow queries or tutorials. Once you have tried some code and are still not getting there, only then try posting a question. Try the Demo link for now.

Comment: @Learner Did you try the demo link?

Comment: Yes. try yourself. you will see the problem

Comment: Its still working on the jsfiddle, can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: So the result is displayed only when I am trying to change the category again and click on the drop-down

Comment: Cant you use menu.addEventListener("change", function() { to do that? Check my edited code.

Comment: @Learner did you understand now?

Comment: How do i ensure that each line is displayed in a new division